# Can i force Google Chrome and FireFox to have the ability to directly edit the documents inside document libraries as in the IE case

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, administration, office-integration

I am working on an on-premises 2013 farm. now i have many documents libraries which have they setting as follow for editing documents:-
[image]

now when i edit a document on IE i will get this dialog, which will allow me to edit the document inside my machine and save the changes to sharepoint automatically:-

[image]

but when i try using google chrome i got inconsistent behavioure, As i will sometimes got this dialog which somehow mimic IE dialog:-
[image]

but sometimes (using the same user) if i click on the same document i will have it downloaded locally:-

[image]

Finally on Firefox i got the worst case, as whenever i click on a document i will get this dialog , which will mainly download the document locally without any link to sharepoint:-
[image]

so i have these 2 questions:-

1. how i can remove the inconsistency inside google chrome? so i will always get the dialog?
2. for Firefox what i can do to have it working as in IE??

now i informed our customer that sharepoint document integration works better with IE.. but they refuse to inform the users that they need to use IE.. as most users use chrome (around 80%) the remaining use IE,Firefox.. so are they any plugin for chrome and for Firefox ??

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en) chrome and firefox extension to behave like IE dialog. Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455212/how-to-open-sharepoint-files-in-chrome-firefox from [@SigarDave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249386/sigardave). It works perfect.

Comment: will those IE tabs still work on newer versions of FireFox & Chrome?? as most of the links which refer to them are somehow old.. an i read that firefox have disabled all the plugin except for flash

Comment: It will definitely work in chrome as its a chrome extension and google can't deprecate extensions as there are hundreds of thousands of extensions out there in chrome store. Firefox used to use plugins that could be from any vendor. Basically IE also uses open document class addon to open the documents in client applications. Chrome and Firefox dont use addons.

Comment: ok i tried the IE tab for chrome, and seems it is working well, the only drawback that users need to manually click on the IE tab to be able to view sharepoint in IE-like inside chrome, i mean i thought this will have effect on normal tabs..but for Firefox where i am using the latest version (55.0.3) , when i tried to install the IE tab from this link https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ie-tab/ i got the this addon not compatible here is the exact message `This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox. `.. so can u advice on the 2 points?

Comment: also for firefox i tried this addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fire-ie/ but seems it does not work with firefix 55.. so not sure if there are any workaround for this on firsfox?

Comment: To be honest, I always suggest my clients to use IE for SharePoint. SharePoint is a Microsoft product and it works well with IE being another Microsoft product. There are other shortcomings in Chrome and Firefox as well like "Open with explorer" or "Connect to Office" works only in IE. I would advise you to suggest your clients to use IE for better SharePoint experience.

Comment: thanks for ur reply and suggestions.. but our customer do not like restricting users to use specific browsers.. what i am planning to do is that i am going to suggest them to use IE tab for chrome, now if they face any problems then it is not my deal as i am not the owner of google !! but now i am trying to find similar functionality for FireFox not sure if there are any other IE tab addon that works well with Firefox 55 ??